# How can I override shared library in LD_LIBRARY_PATH with clang++?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to compile a shared library I wrote in C++ to use a specific version of another shared library in the current directory, however it seems to be ignoring that and it uses the (older and incompatible) .so file in my `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` at runtime. How would I go about overriding the .so file it uses to use my own? I also need to retain the older version for another use on the same system.

Here's my command I'm using to compile: `clang++ /data/openpilot/selfdrive/df/libs/libSNPE.so -lsymphony-cpu -lsymphonypower -I/data/openpilot/phonelibs/snpe/include -std=c++14 -lstdc++ -fPIC -o d_f.so dynamic_follow.cc -shared`

`/data/openpilot/selfdrive/df/libs/libSNPE.so` being the library I want to use.

I also tried to use the `-l` flag before my library file, however it returns `cannot find -l/data/openpilot/selfdrive/df/libs/libSNPE.so`

Confirmed to still use the library in LD_LIBRARY_PATH with this command as well: `clang++ -Wl,-rpath,/data/openpilot/selfdrive/df/libs -L/data/openpilot/selfdrive/df/libs -lSNPE -lsymphony-cpu -lsymphonypower -I/data/openpilot/phonelibs/snpe/include -std=c++14 -stdlib=libc++ -fPIC -o d_f.so dynamic_follow.cc -shared`

Comment: Did you tried -L flag to pass custom libraries directory? something like `-L/data/openpilot/selfdrive/df/libs -lSNPE`

Comment: @stackoverflower Yep, already tried that. Still uses the older version where the ld library path is set

Comment: There might be a way to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH temporary during compilation and linkage if nothing else works.

Comment: I've tried that as well, I set the path before compiling with clang, then set it back and it still uses the old library. Works great if I leave the LD_LIBRARY_PATH or replace the old libraries, but again I need the old version for another part of the project which still uses it.

Answer (score 3):

The `-L` flag tells where to look for libraries at link time, while `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` tells where to look for libraries at run-time. So whatever path you set at link-time, this will be ignored when running the executable.

You need to have `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` include the directory of your dynamic library at *run-time* for your executable to find it. So you may run your executable like this:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/data/openpilot/selfdrive/df/libs:"$LD_LIBRARY_PATH" ./your-exec
```

Comment: I also need to be able to have priority to use the old library in the other section of code, which is Python with cffi so I can't set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH when running the shared library I'm making. Both parts of the Python code are running at the same time continously. Is it possible to set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH while Python is running, from Python?

Comment: Then that would be a totally different question: "How to use two different versions of the same library in one executable?"

Comment: Thanks for this answer! I got weird `undefined reference` and  `undefined symbol` errors, now I know why!